# convergence of a sub-sequence in norm infinity

Tags: real-analysis

The question is, true or false: if fn(x) is bounded in (C[0,1],|| ||infinity) for all n, then there exist a sub-sequence of fn(x), fnk(x) such that fnk(x) converges uniformly in (C[0,1],|| ||infinity).

my answer was false, because {sin(nx)} is a sequence of continuous functions in [0,1] but the set does not have a sub-sequence that converges uniformly in norm infinity.

i want to know if i'm thinking correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine but you have to prove that $\sin (nx)$ does not converge uniformly. Actually, it does not even converge pointwise. To see this take $x=\frac {\pi} 4$ which lies in $[0,1]$. When $n$ is a multiple of $4$ we see that $\sin (nx) \to 0$ whereas when $n$ is an odd number multiplied by $2$ it dose not tend to $0$.